# AVAudioEngine init error

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

When I initialize an AVAudioEngine with this code:

```
_engine = [AVAudioEngine new];
_subMixer = [AVAudioMixerNode new];
_subMixer.volume = 0;
[_engine attachNode:_subMixer];

_audioFormat = [[AVAudioFormat alloc]
                    initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32
                    sampleRate:44100.0
                    channels:1
                    interleaved:NO];  //<AVAudioFormat 0x1c049c200:  1 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32>
[_engine connect:_engine.inputNode to:_subMixer format:_audioFormat];
[_engine connect:_subMixer to:_engine.mainMixerNode format:_audioFormat];
```

Sometime, I got an error `AVAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:896:SetOutputFormat: (IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(hwFormat))]` at `[_engine connect:_engine.inputNode to:_subMixer format:_audioFormat]`.

Then the app crash.
But, this is not inevitable.

The device is iOS 11.2.6 ，iPad mini 4.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with this code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I find what's wrong. I didn't setup AVAudioSession instance before using AVAudioEngine.